# How to perform complex processing over each row in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe as follows

```
Customer_ID   Address_ID    Order_ID    Order_Date
 Cust_1       Addr_1            1       31-Dec-20
 Cust_1       Addr_1            2       23-Jan-21
 Cust_1       Addr_1            3       06-Feb-21
 Cust_1       Addr_2            4       13-Feb-21
 Cust_1       Addr_2            5       20-Feb-21
 Cust_1       Addr_3            6       18-Mar-21
 Cust_1       Addr_3            7       23-Mar-21
 Cust_2       Addr_4            8       31-Dec-20
 Cust_2       Addr_4            9       23-Jan-21
 Cust_2       Addr_4            10      06-Feb-21
 Cust_2       Addr_4            11      13-Feb-21
 Cust_2       Addr_4            12      20-Feb-21
 Cust_2       Addr_5            13      18-Mar-21
 Cust_2       Addr_5            14      23-Mar-21
```

The columns are `customer id`, `address id`, `order id` and `date the order was` placed respectively

The `Order_ID` is always unique

For **every order (every row)**, I need to calculate the order share for a **(customer c1,address a1)** pair

Denoting order_share by **ord_share(c1,a1)** which is defined by the below formula,

```
The total number of orders between (Order_Date) and (Order_Date - 90 days) by c1 from a1  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The total number of orders between (Order_Date) and (Order_Date - 90 days) for all addresses by c1
```

**Note** - underline in the above formula denotes division

90 days here is the window size.
An example from the above table : (I am leaving `order_share` as a fraction for ease of understanding)

**For ORDER_ID 7**:
The total number of orders are 7 - (by Cust_1)
**ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_1) = 3/7, **ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_2) = 2/7, **ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_3) = 2/7

**For ORDER_ID 6**:
The total number of orders are 6 - (by Cust_1)
**ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_1) = 3/6, **ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_2) = 2/6, **ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_3) = 1/6

**For ORDER_ID 5**:
The total number of orders are 5  - (by Cust_1)
**ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_1) = 3, **ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_2) = 2, **ord_share**(Cust_1,Addr_3) = 0

And so on... I need to store these for **all the** rows. My output format should be something like the following

(Is_original_address - this column refers to whether the Address_ID was the original address from which the order was placed)

```
Customer_ID   Address_ID    Order_ID    Order_Share  Is_original_address

Cust_1         Addr_1            7       3/7           0 
Cust_1         Addr_2            7       2/7           0
Cust_1         Addr_3            7       2/7           1
Cust_1         Addr_1            6       3/6           0
Cust_1         Addr_2            6       2/6           0
Cust_1         Addr_3            6       1/6           1
Cust_1         Addr_1            5       3/5           0
Cust_1         Addr_2            5       2/5           1
Cust_1         Addr_3            5       0/5           0 
.
.
.
For all rows
```

So basically, **each row** in the input expands to multiple rows in the output depending on the number of address for the customer

**Note** - the columns in the initial dataframe are not in sorted order or grouped in any order, I just choose such an example to help with explanation

I am finding it very hard to go about this problem. I thought about it a lot, and I can't seem to think of any ways of joining/grouping data to do this since every row is kind of unique. I am really not sure how to get the output dataframe.
From what I can think, I have to clone the original dataframe and for each row, I'll probably have to do multiple group by or joins. I am really unsure how even start implementation.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Please do let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Sorry that I cannot answer more in detail yet, but you should have a look at windows functions (I found tutorials [here](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/) and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-functions-in-sql/)), but I worth you spend some time on these powerful feature if you don't not yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Christophe commented, this uses window functions, but only to calculate the denominator

```py
data=[
    ('c1','a1', 1,'2020-12-31'),
    ('c1','a1', 2,'2021-01-23'),
    ('c1','a1', 3,'2021-02-06'),
    ('c1','a2', 4,'2021-02-13'),
    ('c1','a2', 5,'2021-02-20'),
    ('c1','a3', 6,'2021-03-18'),
    ('c1','a3', 7,'2021-03-23'),
    ('c2','a4', 8,'2020-12-31'),
    ('c2','a4', 9,'2021-01-23'),
    ('c2','a4',10,'2021-02-06'),
    ('c2','a4',11,'2021-02-13'),
    ('c2','a4',12,'2021-02-20'),
    ('c2','a5',13,'2021-03-18'),
    ('c2','a5',14,'2021-03-23'),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = ['c_id','a_id','order_id','order_date'])
df=df.select('c_id','a_id','order_id',F.to_date(F.col('order_date')).alias('date'))
df.createOrReplaceTempView('orders')

spark.sql("""
WITH address_combinations AS (
  SELECT o1.order_id, o2.c_id, o2.a_id
  , CASE WHEN o1.a_id=o2.a_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_original_address
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(o1.date, o2.date) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 THEN 1 END) AS num_orders
  FROM orders o1
  JOIN orders o2 ON o1.c_id=o2.c_id
  GROUP BY o1.order_id, o2.c_id, o2.a_id, is_original_address
)
SELECT c_id, a_id, order_id
, CONCAT(num_orders, '/', SUM(num_orders) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id)) AS order_share
, is_original_address
FROM address_combinations
ORDER BY order_id, a_id
""").show(200)
```

output:

```
+----+----+--------+-----------+-------------------+
|c_id|a_id|order_id|order_share|is_original_address|
+----+----+--------+-----------+-------------------+
|  c1|  a1|       1|        1/1|                  1|
|  c1|  a2|       1|        0/1|                  0|
|  c1|  a3|       1|        0/1|                  0|
|  c1|  a1|       2|        2/2|                  1|
|  c1|  a2|       2|        0/2|                  0|
|  c1|  a3|       2|        0/2|                  0|
|  c1|  a1|       3|        3/3|                  1|
|  c1|  a2|       3|        0/3|                  0|
|  c1|  a3|       3|        0/3|                  0|
|  c1|  a1|       4|        3/4|                  0|
|  c1|  a2|       4|        1/4|                  1|
|  c1|  a3|       4|        0/4|                  0|
|  c1|  a1|       5|        3/5|                  0|
|  c1|  a2|       5|        2/5|                  1|
|  c1|  a3|       5|        0/5|                  0|
|  c1|  a1|       6|        3/6|                  0|
|  c1|  a2|       6|        2/6|                  0|
|  c1|  a3|       6|        1/6|                  1|
|  c1|  a1|       7|        3/7|                  0|
|  c1|  a2|       7|        2/7|                  0|
|  c1|  a3|       7|        2/7|                  1|
|  c2|  a4|       8|        1/1|                  1|
|  c2|  a5|       8|        0/1|                  0|
|  c2|  a4|       9|        2/2|                  1|
|  c2|  a5|       9|        0/2|                  0|
|  c2|  a4|      10|        3/3|                  1|
|  c2|  a5|      10|        0/3|                  0|
|  c2|  a4|      11|        4/4|                  1|
|  c2|  a5|      11|        0/4|                  0|
|  c2|  a4|      12|        5/5|                  1|
|  c2|  a5|      12|        0/5|                  0|
|  c2|  a4|      13|        5/6|                  0|
|  c2|  a5|      13|        1/6|                  1|
|  c2|  a4|      14|        5/7|                  0|
|  c2|  a5|      14|        2/7|                  1|
+----+----+--------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Not sure if this is needed, but here is the exact same SQL re-implemented using Python `df` APIs:

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window

(
    df.alias('o1')
    .join(df.alias('o2')
          , on=F.col('o1.c_id')==F.col('o2.c_id')
          , how='inner'
         )
    .select(F.col('o1.order_id'), F.col('o2.c_id'), F.col('o2.a_id')
            , F.when(F.datediff(F.col('o1.date'),F.col('o2.date')).between(0, 90), 1).alias('is_order')
            , F.when(F.col('o1.a_id')==F.col('o2.a_id'), 1).otherwise(0).alias('is_original_address')
           )
    .groupby('order_id','c_id','a_id','is_original_address')
    .agg(F.count('is_order').alias('num_orders'))
    .select('c_id','a_id','order_id'
            , F.concat(F.col('num_orders')
                       , F.lit('/')
                       , F.sum('num_orders').over(Window.partitionBy('order_id'))
                      ).alias('order_share')
            , 'is_original_address'
           )
    .sort('order_id','a_id')
).show(200)
```

Quick explanation:
`address_combinations` first self-joins the orders table with itself to get all possible combinations. However, there may be duplicates, so we perform `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` the number of orders within the 90d time window.

The next part simply gives us the denominator and formats it as desired ("x/y")

Hope this meets your requirements!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it worked. I was trying to get the output using operations on the dataframe `df` but was finding it difficult to do so. I am still wondering if it's possible to get the same output using `df` without SQL?

Comment: I believe most, if not, all SQL functions are also available as [python APIs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql.html#functions). I've added on the re-implementation to my answer, if that's what you needed

Comment: Thanks a lot. The earlier one suits my needs. Just wanted to know the same equivalent in PySpark as well